# How to make encrypted board idx

Tags: php, md5, substr

Now I'm making a board, but there are some issues.

I have to hide my board's contents idx.

Normally(When we use `$_GET`), `board.php?idx=1(or some number)`. But I want hide or encrypt this.

I considered using `md5` but it's too long, So I cut this by 5 char using `substr` function. but I'm worried about duplicated situation, When I use front 5 char.

So My question is 
 Is there effective way to encrypt the idx?

Thanks for reading

Comment: How do you know the value, if you use MD5?

Comment: I tried to save the md5 value and search by md5 value on databases... My goal is just prevent to track the board contents on url

Comment: @user3509135, if you just need to remove it from URL - you can use POST request instead of GET (still it can be found by any kind of sniffer).

Comment: Ok, and why is MD5 to long?

Comment: @WhiteAngel thanks for your suggestion. I'll consider about that too.

Comment: @user3509135, if you really need encryption - you can use any you like. E.g. RSA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29. This will protect your system for sure and there are libraries for almost all known languages. But you need to think if you really need to add so much complexity to your system.
If you just need something to hide - you can describe your situation better and we can try to find much easier way.

Comment: @S.Pols If i use md5 even I set string "1" it will be over 32 characters :C

Comment: Yeah true, but it doesn't matter if you hash "1" or the text of a whole book. It will still remain 32 characters.

Comment: Also note MD5 is not encryption, it's hashing!

Comment: You may use base36 encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36#PHP_implementation) which is quite short, but with a hash you will always have to deal with possible collisions. If you don't want this you can always create your own numerical->alpha mapping/cipher.